# Node.js - Restify POST Mocha test failing

Tags: node.js, post, mocha.js, restify

**I  get the error "invalid Response from /post"**

at main.js:23:27
      at parseResponse (node_modules/restify/lib/clients/json_client.js:91:9)
      at IncomingMessage.done (node_modules/restify/lib/clients/string_client.js:165:13)
      at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:913:12)

**Here is my Code:**

```
function get_settings(req, res, next) {
var text = "";
req.setEncoding("utf8");
res.send(200, {ok: 'ok'});
}
var server = restify.createServer({
name: 'test',
version: '0.0.1'});

server.use(restify.acceptParser(server.acceptable));
server.use(restify.queryParser());
server.use(restify.bodyParser());

server.post('/post', get_settings );

server.listen(5177,function() {
console.log('%s listening at %s', server.name, server.url);
});
```

**Mocha Test:**

```
var restify = require('restify');
var assert = require('assert');

// init the test client
var client = restify.createJsonClient({
url: 'http://141.37.168.79:5177',
version: '*'
});

describe('service: post endpoint', function() {

// Test #1
describe('200 response check', function() {
it('should get a 200 response', function(done) {
    client.post('/post', { hello: 'world' }, function(err, req, res, data) {                
        if (err) {
            throw new Error(err);
        }
        else {

            if (data.code) != 200) {
                throw new Error('invalid response from /post');
            }
            done();
        }
    });
});
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

At first sight

```
if (data.code) != 200)
```

doesn't look good. You have an extra parenthesis there.

Apart from that, I think the way you access the status code is using res.statusCode